# How to parse JSON string using GSON?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a JSON object that contains the string of other key value types. Below is my JSON code:

```
{
  "objs": [
    {
      "obj1": {
        "ID1": 1,
        "ID2": 2
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How to parse that `"ID1"` and `"ID2"`?

Comment: you json is not in a valid format. check 
@javaboygo post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create classes, add variables and tag them for Deserialization:

```
public class Root {
    @SerializedName("objs")
    public List<Obj> objects;
}

public class Obj {
    @SerializedName("obj1")
    public Obj1 obj1;
}

public class Obj1 {
    @SerializedName("ID1")
    public int ID1;

    @SerializedName("ID2")
    public int ID2;
}
```

Then Deserialize your JSON:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Root root = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Root.class);
```

Comment: But here ID1 and ID2 are inside Quotes. Can't able parse that.

Comment: In that case this solution will not work. I tried removing Obj1 class and used a String variable instead (inside Obj class), but it still throws a MalformedJsonException. Sites like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and [Json Validator](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) are also giving the same output. You need to reformat your Json, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Got a solution...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of that JSON would be:

```
{"objs":[
          {"obj1":
                  {"ID1":1,"ID2":2}
          }
        ]
}
```

If you want use GSON:

```
JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonLine);
JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("objs");
JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("obj1");
jobject = jarray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
String ID1 = jobject.get("ID1").toString();
String ID2 = jobject.get("ID2").toString();
```